# Populating a vector in parallel, order not important

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, parallel-processing, stdthread

I have to create a vector of k elements. Every thread will create its portion, let's say k * 25% and must place it into the vector, at any index. Driven from this [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/thread/), I was about to do something like this:

```
std::atomic<std::vector<aClass<templatedType>>> H;
```

but this won't work:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/atomic:823:13: error: 
      _Atomic cannot be applied to type
      'std::__1::vector<StableHashFunction<int>,
      std::__1::allocator<StableHashFunction<int> > >' which is not trivially
      copyable
    mutable _Atomic(_Tp) __a_;
```

since it's not trivially copyable - and the workaround is not sweet. Moreover, do I need it to be atomic?

That's the question, when I do not care about the order, should I still use an atomic? In other words, do the data races affect only the order of the elements, or they can cause other side-effects, like dodging an element (so instead of k elements, to only have k - 1 in the end)?

Comment: `push_back()` or `emplace_back()` aren't atomic operations, thus you have to protect them with some synchronization mechanism like a `std::mutex`.

Comment: Create a vector of size K, then each thread update portion of the vector, so you don't share data between threads.

Comment: @Jarod42 That was my first thought too but to do that you need to default construct all the elements in the vector.

Comment: What @Jarod42 wrote, or first create 4 separate per-thread vectors, merge them on end. (also the sizes will be known already, so you can reserve correct size for the final one). ... If you know the expected workload, `reserve` anyway, then `push_back` will not need to reallocate vector when growing.

Comment: @Nathan - no you don't, you need to be able to supply suitable constructor arguments when you instantiate the vector, but you don't need a default constructor for the elements.

Comment: @latedeveloper Same difference.  You still have to construct all the elements in the vector if you want to split the vector into multiple threads and have each thread manipulate a section of it.

Comment: Ped7g I was thinking of creating as much sub-vectors as the threads number and then merge (after every subvec has been populated). However, @πάνταῥεῖ seems to have the answer for the question posted, in its generic form. Do you want to post an answer, or my question should be deleted? I mean all of you great guys seen it, but didn't upvote. Well, on second thought, nobody downvote it ... =)

Comment: BTW, my first idea was to split workload evenly, and let each thread to write at `[index*thread_nums + thread_id]` - interleave writes (and `size` first), but that may actually hurt cache mechanisms when several cores are modifying the same page of memory. So having per-thread local vectors is better, merging them together at end. In case the merge is too expensive (no element copy viable), just create meta vector containing the original local vectors, and add one more `for each` to proceed the meta list of vectors.

Comment: @gsamaras Well, if you do what I proposed, it makes only sense if you have CPU intensive efforts to calculate the values that should be used to initialize the vector. And don't worry, I'm just upvoting rarely in general ;).

Comment: BTW, just a not on @πάνταῥεῖ answer about mutexes... If you need to split workload into different threads, then you probably care about performance. If you care about performance, you should write every parallelization as much mutex-less/atomic-less/share-memory-less, as possible, as syncing between threads is so costly, that you may throw away all the time you saved by running in parallel. So as long as your vector calculation is independent between threads, make sure the target memory is too, then you don't need any locking and syncing, just waiting for all threads to finish + merge result.

Comment: I agree @Ped7g, both of you have great tips, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you try inserting items in parallel, problems happen only when the vector must change its size: concurrent insertions would have to update the same locations in memory, causing incorrect behavior (crashes, lost items, etc.)

However, setting different elements of an existing vector concurrently does not cause a problem, so a common solution to this problem is pre-allocating the vector.

This approach requires a default constructor of vector element, and an upfront knowledge of exact number of items that each thread is going to place into the vector. For example, if you know that thread 0 is going to place 100 elements, thread 1 is going to place 120 elements, and thread 2 is going to place 110 elements, you pre-allocate a vector of 100+120+110 elements, and give each thread its own initial index: 0, 100, and 220. Now each thread can place items into the vector without running into concurrency problems.

[image: Vector subdivision]

Comment: I'm curious about line cache. What happens if elements at indices 99 and 100 are on same cache line?

Comment: @Amadeus That is called false sharing and is a valid concern.  If the threads both start at the beginning and go to the end you probably won't see it.

Comment: @Amadeus This shouldn't create much problem: the core that happens to write first will invalidate the cache line of the other core, so it would have to read from memory the next time the data is requested. All you see is a small slow-down, which shouldn't even be a problem, because by the time the first thread is about to write to location 99, the second thread should be long done with location 100, writing all the way up to location 199 or so.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use atomic with vector or another class, you can use pointer instead. I think in your case you have to use mutex to make thread safe access to the vector, or use [TBB library](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/intel-tbb-tutorial) . This library has all necessary functional for you task.

Comment: I don't want to use any library, but thanks for the tip, +1 for the future user that might be interested.